# Finding the joint density function from other distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

**Problem:** Find the Let X, Y two dependent random variables. let Z = X + Y . Suppose X, Z have the joint pdf $f_{X,Z}$.

Find the joint distribution of $f_{X, Y}$.

**Attempt:**
We can find the distribution of $f_X$ from the joint distribution of X and Z. Then, we can also find the distribution of Z in a similar fashion.

Then, my attempt is to use the fact that Z = X + Y but am not sure how to go about it. First, we can say that Y = Z - X and then solve for the cumulative distribution function, however, this is not going to work as this would result in the distribution of just Y. Since Y and X are dependent, we can't find use these results together.

Not sure how to go about this problem...

Comment: You get the PDF $f_{X,Y}$ from its CDF which is $\mathbb P\{X\le x,Y\le y\}=\mathbb P\{X\le x,Z-X\le y\}\,.$ This you can calculate with the known CDF $f_{X,Z}\,.$

Comment: Okay, with the hint: $F_{X,Y}(x, y) = F_{X,Z}(x, y+x)$. Is this the right idea? My thinking is that since the R.V. X is bounded under small x, then the sum of y and x will be bounding Z. To find the pdf, we just take the derivative w.r.t. x and y.

Comment: I recommend to put into that vacuum a concrete example of a PDF $f_{X,Z}$ where $X$ and $Z$ are dependent and calculate $\mathbb P\{X\le x,Z-X\le y\}\,.$

Comment: Or independent. If that's easier.